# my file system error : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not date

Tags: python, makefile, operating-system, python-datetime

my code should be create file by each day,

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
d4 = today.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")
print("today=", d4)

os.makedirs(today)
```

Answer (score 0):

`today` variable returns date object while `os.makedirs` is looking for str object for dirs name.

If you want to make the date as the name of the file, try to cast the date object into str object.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
d4 = today.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")
print("today=", d4)

os.makedirs(str(today))
```

That should work fine.